# Do nested packages always have to be within nested folders in Python?

Tags: python

Can someone give an example on when you write the following in Python

```
import p3 from p1.p2
```

`p1`, `p2` are not folders but files. I am trying to understand the **sparsely** documented import system with (confusing ?) docs and (less) examples.

Comment: Where are you encountering this?

Comment: The example you gave in the question will result in a syntax error. The correct way to import p3 from p1.p2 would be "from p1.p2 import p3", not "import p3 from p1.p2"

Answer (score -1):

Packages and importing are well documented in the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Packages can be composed in a hierarchy that does not necessarily reflect a directory structure. In your case, package `p1` is importing `p2` which in turn imports `p3`. All these packages can be in the same directory.

```
# p1.py
import p2 # p2 is now accessible within this package

# p2.py
import p3 # p3 is now accessible within this package

# p3.py
some_variable = 'ding!'
```

With this import hierarchy, I can import `p1` and walk the hierarchy like this

```
import p1
print p1.p2.p3.some_variable
# ding!
```

Or I can import a sub-package from within the hierarchy

```
from p1 import p2
# or
from p1.p2 import p3
print p3.some_variable
```

Directory structures *can* be used to organize packages more cleanly. A directory can be turned into an importable module by adding an `__init__.py` file into it. You can do similar importing strategies inside these init files.

Comment: The imports you show are not actually enough to perform imports like `from p1.p2 import p3`. Also, you have your `from` imports backward.